# Publicar proyecto con carpeta vacía en Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

¿Cómo se hace para que, al publicar un proyecto web en VS2010, **publique también una carpeta que se encuentra vacía**?

Investigando un poco, vi que se podía hacer incluyendo un archivo cualquiera dentro de esta carpeta, darle a propiedades y seleccionarlo como "contenido", de esta manera me incluye la carpeta (y también el archivo).

¿No existe una forma más limpia, por llamarlo de una manera, de publicar el proyecto solo con la carpeta vacía que necesito?

Comment: ¿donde la publicaste?

Comment: En el servidor compa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El Procedimiento más limpio es modificar el "post build event" y adicionar allí el comando para crear la carpeta. Esto lo haces desde las propiedades del proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto cada vez que el proyecto haga build la carpeta se creará, y esto incluye el build que se va en el webdeploy.

"**post-build event**"  está disponible si tu aplicación web debe esta creada como **Web Project** no como **Web Site**.  Mira los siguientes screenshots.

[image: Menú nuevo web project]

[image: web project wizard]

En **VS 2010** también puedes usar "**post-build event**"

#### [Cómo: Especificar eventos de compilación (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-co/library/ke5z92ks(v=vs.100).aspx)

**Otra opción** es crear el folder en el proyecto de VS y allí colocar un archivo cualquiera , por ejemplo dummy.txt y marcar así las propiedades de este archivo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Y una opción más** , siempre puedes encapsular el uso de esa carpeta en tu código fuente, y preguntar que si la carpeta no existe  entonces la cree.

```cs
var file = new FileInfo(fPath);
file.Directory.Create(); // Si la carpeta donde debe estar el archivo ya existe entonces no hace nada
File.WriteAllText(file.FullName, content);
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta, ahora, si no me equivoco el "post-build event", no esta disponible para VS2010, pero las otras opciones si. Saludos

Comment: "post-build event"  si está disponible pero tu aplicación web debe estar creada como Web Project no como Web Site. También está disponible para VS 2010. He Adicionado más info complementaria del tema en la respuesta,

Comment: @JuanK +1 a la respuesta "visual" (por las imagenes detalladas)

Comment: @JuanK muchísimas gracias estimado!